# Formulaire SQL AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, sql, ajax

Hello i have look for a lot of tuto about how to do a good formulaire with php and ajax and i actually try to start from a code that a friend gave me. i actually succes to send the request but it looks like the data that i get are empty ... may you have a look and tel me if i have an error or something ?

Formulaire.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>


<form id="formulaire" name="form1" method="get">
<p class="titre">Coordonnées</p>


  <label>Nom : </label>
    <input type="text" name="nom" size="30" /><br />
    <label>Prenom : </label>
    <input type="text" name="prenom" size="30" /><br />
  <label>Adresse mail : </label>
    <input type="text" name="mail" size="30" /><br />
    <label>Telephone : </label>
    <input type="text" name="telephone" size="30" /><br />
    <label>Code postal : </label>
    <input type="text" name="codepostal" size="30" /><br />

</form>
<img src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Service/edi.jpg" style="cursor:pointer; width:50px;"onclick="Formulaire();">


<script type="text/javascript">
    function Formulaire()
    {
        var nom = $(document).find(".champ[name=nom]").val();
        var prenom = $(document).find(".champ[name=prenom]").val();
        var mail = $(document).find(".champ[name=mail]").val();
        var telephone = $(document).find(".champ[name=telephone]").val();
        var codepostal = $(document).find(".champ[name=codepostal]").val();

        var regex = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z_éàèôïâê@. 0-9]","i");
        var regextel = new RegExp("#^0[1-68]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$#");
        var regexmail = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(([\.\-\_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)?)\@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.\-\_])+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$");

        /*if(regex.test(nom) == true || regex.test(prenom) == true || regexmail.test(mail) == false || regex.test(telephone) == true || regex.test(codepostal) == true ||
           nom == "" || prenom == "" || mail == "" || telephone == "" || codepostal == "")
        {
            alert ("Veuillez remplir tous les champs correctement");
        }
        else
        {*/
            $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "http://formatfactory.biz/lib/php/form2.php",data: "idcrea=vengeance&nom="+nom+"&prenom="+prenom+"&mail="+mail+"&telephone="+telephone+"&codepostal="+codepostal,success: function(html)
            {
                alert(html);
            }
            });
        //}
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Form2.php

```
<?php

//Connexion à la DB avant d'effectuer notre requête

require_once ('connect.php');


$nom = isset($_POST['nom']) ? $_POST['nom'] : "";

$prenom = isset($_POST['prenom']) ? $_POST['prenom'] : "";


$mail = isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail'] : "";

$codepostal = isset($_POST['codepostal']) ? $_POST['codepostal'] : "";



$telephone = isset($_POST['telephone']) ? $_POST['telephone'] : "";


try {



    $sql = "INSERT INTO vengeance (nom, prenom, mail ,telephone, codepostal) VALUES ('".$nom."','".$prenom."','".$mail."','".$telephone."','".$codepostal."')";

    // On exécute la requête

    $req = $db->exec($sql);

    $db = null;

 }

catch(PDOException $e)

{

   echo "Erreur";

}



?>
```

Comment: j'aime bien la france :P it looks like you never submit your form....neither with `action` attribute, nor with JS's `.submit()` method

Comment: First remark: never use "GET" when you're inserting the data in a database. Use "POST"!

Comment: @messerbill Yes, you're right. The function `Formulaire` is just declared, but never called.

Comment: The formulaire method is call when i click on the image é_è : "onclick="Formulaire();">

Comment: Do you think that my table is filled with empty value because of the Get method ?

Comment: No, the "GET" method is a security risk when writing to the database. For this purpose you should always use the "POST" method. The values are empty because your input fields lack the class `champ`. The error is in your function `Formulaire`. I'm writing at the moment a longer answer with some explanations.

Comment: you can also have a look inside of your devTool, there you can see every HTTP request and response

Comment: So i changed the method for POST and changed the way to get the value of the champ now i use : var nom = document.getElementById("name").value;

Comment: Thx for your help people :)

Comment: How do i flag this question as answered please :) ?

Comment: don't know what finally made your success....just type an answer by yourself ;)

Comment: @AshleyDadsetan I just finished my answer with some tips and a simpler way to submit the form with AJAX. If you like it, you can accept it.

Comment: Since you use JQuery you can also do `var nom = $('#name').val()`. You can also edit the tags and add `jquery` as it is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my proposals.

Change this line:

```
<form id="formulaire" name="form1" method="get">
```

to:

```
<form id="formulaire" name="form1" method="post">
```

If you want an image as submit button, then you have to use:

```
<input
    type="image"
    src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Service/edi.jpg"
    style="cursor:pointer; width:50px;">
```

and don't call the function with onclick event from there. You're using jQuery.
Just place the `input type="image"` inside the form, before the closing `</form>` tag.

Don't name your JavaScript functions with capital letter, unless they are constructor functions. You're breaking the conventions. So don't use:

```
function Formulaire()
```

Instead use something like:

```
function envoyerFormulaire()
```

or

```
function sendForm()
```

In your function you are trying to get the value of an element with the CSS class `champ` and value "nom" for the attribute `name`:

```
var nom = $(document).find(".champ[name=nom]").val();
```

But your input fields don't have the class `champ`. That is why you get empty values.

Here is another way to submit the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formulaire').submit(function (event) { // get the form with id formulaire
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent sending the form by the browser
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://formatfactory.biz/lib/php/form2.php",
            data: $('#formulaire').serialize() // serialize the form
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            // do something if form sent
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            // do something if submit failed
        });
    });
});
```

When using jQuery this is the most common way to submit a form per AJAX.

As you see, there is no need to get the value of every single field manually.

Bonne chance!